# Difference between local and global variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed that in JavaScript, Inside  a function some times a variable created without mentioning `var` before it.

For example :

```
function myfunction() {
     x = 10;
     var y = 10;
}
```

what is the difference between these both?

Comment: I'd look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function myact() {
  x = 20;
  var y = 10;
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
}
myact();
console.log(x);
//y not available here
```

`var` is used for declaration. So, assigning without declaration will simply give it global scope meaning: it will first search if it is available in any scope stack above, if not creates the variable implicitly in global scope and assigns.

[`JS Docs says:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

> The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution
>   context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables
>   declared outside any function, global.
>
> Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a
>   global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the
>   assignment is executed.

Comment: even though, undeclared variable is in a child function, it becomes global object, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Will put up a simple demo

Comment: just mark it as a dupe, no need to answer this question over and over...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it

Comment: didn't see the dup comment. kinda obvious it would have been answered rite.

Comment: @IamSarav yes, u r right.

Comment: @Iceman thanks a lot for your quick response and helping me! :)